# Is it possible to create a service or application which can programmatically logon a user in windows

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winforms

Is it possible to create a service or application which can programmatically logon  a user in when windows server(2003 and 2008) starts up.
if possible how to write a program in c#, And how to hook the windows.

Comment: I don't know about the Server editions, but it's definitely possible in a hackish way in XP and 7. I'm fairly sure there's a much easier and more reliable way to do what you want, though.

Comment: Being able to use search engines is rare, but valuable skill - try to learn it. One of top results for "windows autologon" - [Micorosft/SysInternals Autologon for Windows v3.01](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905.aspx)

Comment: Why do you want a service or application to do this, what is the real problem you are trying to solve? Ask that question instead.

Comment: all logon windows users work on under my program control.if user logon with my service we will take care of user all activities, means start up programs and instated explorer.exe working my custom my.exe and ext..

Comment: @user2542069: Ok, so it's another XY problem. Don't write such a service. Instead, google Group Policy Objects (GPO).

Answer (score 3):

If you create a Windows Service project you may create a ProjectInstaller containing a ServiceInstaller object, one property of which is whether the service is to start automatically whenever the system starts. You may also specify which account you wish it to run under, including the username and password, as properties of the ProjectInstaller's ServiceProcessInstaller object.

For a tutorial on how to create such a service have a look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396428.aspx).

A Windows Service may not, however, have a UI (you mention wanting to "hook the windows"?) unless you associate a NotifyIcon with the service that the user clicks on to bring up a window.